# According to sedeprivationism, does a material pope have temporal authority?

Tags: papacy, civil-government, authority, sedevacantism, sedeprivationism

According to [sedeprivationism](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6641), does a material pope (*papa materialiter*) have [temporal authority](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2989)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John of St. Thomas ([CURSUS THEOLOGICUS In Summa Thelologicam D. Thomas, Tomus VII, IN SECUNDAM SECUNDÆ DIVI THOMÆ, Quæstio I, DE FIDE, DE AUCTORITATE SUMMI PONTIFICIS, Parisiis Ludovixus Vivês, Editor, 1886, p. 207, sq.](https://isidore.co/misc/Res%20pro%20Deo/Dominican/Fr.%20Albert/from%20Fr.%20Albert,%20O.P./JSTh%20On%20the%20Deposition%20of%20a%20pope%20ENG-LAT.epub)) seems to think a heretical pope can exercise (albeit illegitimately/tyrannically) temporal power:

> [The Church] may defend itself, not by deposing him [a heretical pope], but by repelling him with force if he proceeds with violence or tyrannically, if, for example, he wished to do something against justice by the force of arms, one could repulse him with arms; and similarly, if he were to establish something against good morals he is not to be obeyed, because an unjust law does not oblige.